# vagrant, install chef/centos-6.6

Tags: vagrant, centos6

My vagrant version is:

```
$ vagrant --version
Vagrant version 1.0.1
```

Following [these instructions](https://atlas.hashicorp.com/chef/boxes/centos-6.6), `vagrant init` works:

```
$ vagrant init chef/centos-6.6
A `Vagrantfile` has been placed in this directory. You are now
ready to `vagrant up` your first virtual environment! Please read
the comments in the Vagrantfile as well as documentation on
`vagrantup.com` for more information on using Vagrant.
```

But `vagrant up` can't find the box:

```
$ vagrant up 
There was a problem with the configuration of Vagrant. The error message(s)
are printed below:

vm:
* The box 'chef/centos-6.6' could not be found.
```

What is the way to configure `vagrant`, or the command line option, to use `chef/centos-6.6`?

Answer (score 2):

Chef has removed all of their boxes from atlas. They have left a comment here https://atlas.hashicorp.com/chef/ saying:

> If you are looking for Bento boxes they now have their own
>   organization https://atlas.hashicorp.com/bento/

Answer (score 1):

If you trigger a:

```
vagrant box add chef/centos-6.6
```

with the outdated source (chef) it will provide feedback leading to bento as the new source, something along the lines of:

> Name: **bento**/centos-6.6
>   Provider: virtualbox
>   Version: 2.2.0

This eventually makes more concrete what is written on the site at the [chef atlas link](https://atlas.hashicorp.com/chef/), that the command in your question shall now instead be:

```
$ vagrant init bento/centos-6.6
```

(replacing chef by **bento**)

Answer (score -3):

Some time ago hashicorp moved their images to atlas. Boxes are now downloaded here:
https://atlas.hashicorp.com/boxes/search

Your box is here:
https://atlas.hashicorp.com/chef/boxes/centos-6.6

I can download the box with Vagrant 1.7.2. You are using 1.0.1.

So i think it's a version issue. You have to install a newer version.

Comment: The link to the Chef box provides a 404 response because the underlying image has since moved.